# MS Project/PWA Approvals When Dates Change

Tags: workflow, project, powerapps, ms-project

Is there a way to lock down PWA schedules and require an approval work flow to change dates? Maybe using Power Apps? I am looking to implement a simple change control process.

I have been googling and can't find any information on how to do this with MS Project.